# Rails where clause when something is stored as array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, activerecord

I am running rails 4.2, with a PG database.

I have an item stored in the database such as (model `Item`):

```
:something => ["1", "2", "3"]
```

I would like to get the `Item.where(:something.include? => "3")`

Obviously this is not working - but how are you meant to do this in rails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [*documentation*](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array), something like this should work:

```
Item.where('something @> ARRAY[?]::varchar[]', ['3'])
```

Comment: According to the doc, there is a shorter method to use when we are looking for only one element.

`Item.where("'3' = ANY (something)")`

I'm quite chocked there no easier activerecord's method to do it!

Comment: @MaxChrétien: Can I (or you) include your comment in the answer? I think it can be considered quite useful.

Comment: Comment rejected. _This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer._

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @potashin answer, there is a shorter way to do (see [documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array)) if you need to get Items on *one* element.

```
# Items for a single something
  Item.where("'3' = ANY (something)")
  # Or using '?'
  Item.where('? = ANY (something)', '3')

# Items for multiple something
  Item.where('something @> ARRAY[?]::varchar[]', ['3', '4'])
```