# Selecting Records where the ID is in a list of ID stored as an attribute

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have these to tables in my database, `Locations` and `Services`

Each `Location` record has an attribute called `location_ids` which is a comma-separated list of ids*.

*I represented my many-to-many relationship like this because I have many tables similar to `Services` and did not want to have a ton of link tables

**my tables**

```
CREATE TABLE services (
  id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  location_ids varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  image varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  created_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  created_by bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  updated_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  updated_by bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE locations (
  id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  street1 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  street2 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  city varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  province varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  country varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  postal_code varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  phone1 varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  phone2 varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  fax varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  email varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  twitter_url varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  facebook_url varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  created_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  created_by bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  updated_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  updated_by bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
);
```

I am trying to retrieve all the `Services` where the ID of a specific location (that I get from my params) is in that `location_ids` attribute.

**This is the query that I have (doesn't work) it might make it clearer what I was trying to retrieve**

`Admin::Service.where("#{params[:location_id]} in (services.location_ids)")`

*params[:location_id] would be the id of the current location

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update**

I ended adding 5 link tables in my database, makes it easier and more accessible through Rails.
Thanks everyone who helped

Comment: Looks like service doesnt have a column named location ids , its location id

Comment: that is actually a type sorry about that, I fixed it

Comment: You basically can only do a SQL `LIKE` query to get all rows that have the id somewhere in the `location_id` string. But I recommend not to follow this path for two reasons: 1) It will be very slow, because `LIKE` queries cannot use indexes. 2) You will have to deal with cases were searching for the ID `%123%` finds records with `location_id` like this: `1234, 4567`. My advice is: Do not fight Rails conventions, use a common `has_and_belongs_to` relation.

Comment: Does that mean having link_tables for my relationships would be simpler and more efficient even if it means having more tables?

Comment: Yes, that would be simpler to implement (because it follos Rails conventions) and would have a much better performance!

Comment: Okay, I see. I was trying to avoid having a couple more tables but I think it just got more complicated in the end. Thanks for the help, I'll get to working on that.

Comment: `comma-separated list of ids` - my heart sinks each time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails where clause when something is stored as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893755/rails-where-clause-when-something-is-stored-as-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding link tables in my database. The work it took to add them is far less than the work it would have caused me to do later in my project.

**Example of what I used**

For my services, I created a table called location_services with attributes `ID`, `location_id`, `service_id`.
In my model for Service in Rails, I did

**In my Service model**

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
    has_many location_services, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :locations, through: :location_services
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :location_services
end
```

**In my LocationService model**

```
class LocationService < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :location, optional: true
     belongs_to :service, optional: true
end
```

**And in my Location model**

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :location_services, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :services, through: :location_services
end
```

I then repeated these steps for each of my tables that had a many-to-many relationship to my `locations` table

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @spickermann. I strongly encourage you to use has_and_belongs_to_many or has_many :through relationships. Anyway, I believe this should work (not recommended).

```
Admin::Service.all.select{ |service| 
    service.location_ids.split(',').map(&:to_i).include?(params[:location_id])
}
```